# How can I check if my IIS is alive using C#?

Tags: c#, winforms

How can I check if my IIS is alive using C#?

If the server is down - how to do iisreset ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using WebRequest to try opening a page? If it doesn't return anything to you then perhaps use the Process class to call iisreset.

```
// Initialise the WebRequest.
WebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create("[your URI here]");
// Return the response. 
WebResponse webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse();
// Close the response to free resources.
webResponse.Close();

if (webResponse.ContentLength > 0) // May have to catch an exception here instead
{
    Process.Start("iisreset.exe", "/reset"); // Or whatever arg you want

}
```

It needs finessing but this is the broad outline of what you asked for...

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new WebRequest to localhost. If you get a response, that means your IIS is up, if not, it's down.

To reset it, create a new Process and pass iisreset as an argument.

Comment: Better yet do the request via the external IP of the Server, maybe even via an external proxy.